# Email signature displaying slices between segments

Tags: html, email, outlook, gmail, html-email

I recently created a html email signature and it formats correctly in my browser and looks great, however, as soon as i paste it into Outlook or Gmail, every slice is visible. I've tried a few novice changes, but I'm pretty clueless so struggling to see where the error is.

Below is the code that I am using - can anyone see any issues? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
    td {line-height:0; font-size: 0.0em; }
    img { display: block; float: left; padding: 0; align: absbottom; align: texttop; }
</style>
</head> 

<!-- PASTE YOUR CODE BELOW HERE -->


<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (ROBERT_EMAIL_SIGNATURE.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="1081" height="361" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="9">
            <img src="images/_01.png" width="1080" height="116" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="116" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" rowspan="4">
            <img src="images/_02.png" width="959" height="93" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/bollostore/"><img src="images/_03.png" width="31" height="30" alt=""></a></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="10">
            <img src="images/_04.png" width="90" height="176" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="30" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/_05.png" width="31" height="18" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="18" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/bollo-store/"><img src="images/_06.png" width="31" height="31" alt=""></a></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="31" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/_07.png" width="31" height="18" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="14" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="9">
            <img src="images/_08.png" width="135" height="151" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
            <a href="mailto:info@bollostore.com"><img src="images/_09.png" width="204" height="29" alt=""></a></td>
        <td colspan="3" rowspan="6">
            <img src="images/_10.png" width="620" height="83" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="4" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
             <a href="https://www.facebook.com/BOLLOstore/?locale=en_GB"><img src="images/_11.png" width="31" height="31" alt=""></a></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="25" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/_12.png" width="204" height="20" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="6" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/_13.png" width="31" height="48" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="14" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="tel:01415525552"><img src="images/_14.png" width="162" height="29" alt=""></a></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/_15.png" width="42" height="48" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="29" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/_16.png" width="162" height="19" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="5" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/_17.png" width="565" height="14" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">
            <a href="https://www.bollostore.com"><img src="images/_18.png" width="141" height="43" alt=""></a></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/_19.png" width="35" height="68" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="14" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
                <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/BOLLOstore/@55.8617721,-4.3668751,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x488846a1a6df851f:0x3c4bf6eb1a637f2c!8m2!3d55.8617691!4d-4.3643002!16s%2Fg%2F11hd6mx234"><img src="images/_20.png" width="455" height="29" alt=""></a></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/_21.png" width="314" height="54" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="29" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="images/_22.png" width="455" height="25" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="images/_23.png" width="141" height="25" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="25" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="135" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="162" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="42" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="251" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="314" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="55" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="31" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="55" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="spacer.gif" width="35" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>






<!-- PASTE YOUR CODE ABOVE HERE -->
</html>
```

Comment: Have you also considered how it should look on mobile, given 80%+ of people consume email on mobiles? They can't display 1000px+ images, or zoom out impossibly small. (But to answer the question, try inlining the styles.)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to upload the images on a server so other people can get a better understanding of the issue, I recommend using postimage.org.

My advice is to use Gmail on the web browser, It will keep many of your stiles and will display properly on mobile and desktop. Try using inline styles as well, and when possible use attributes instead of style, the more HTML you use the better, the email provider can change the CSS rules, but it is less likely to do that with HTML.

I hope that helps!